# how to know the action type in JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've MVC 5 application and In the java script file I need to know if im on edit or create mode in the view (change some control accordingly)?I mean the action

how should I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    var action = '@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString()';
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,Should I put it as is in the JS file?

Comment: You can get it everywhere in the view (js or html).

Comment: You cant get it in external js file. If you want to get it in an external js file you can pass it as parameter to any js function.

Comment: Thanks but when I use it in action i get this value in debgger "@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString()" ,do I need to add something?